# Django Rest Framework: Cannot serialize or save uploaded image

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-settings, django-serializer, django-uploads

Cannot serialize or save uploaded an image in APIview.
If saving, a file is broken and cannot be open. If serialzing, getting:
***{"avatar":["No file was submitted."]}***
Request content:

```
MultiValueDict: {u'name': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: Avatar.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}
```

Settings:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
```

URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^test/$', TestReturn.as_view(), name='test-detail'),
url(r'^users/$', UserProfileAll.as_view(), name='userprofile-detail'),
url(r'^avatar/', UploadAvatar.as_view(), name='images')

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Model:

```
class AvatarStorage(models.Model):
avatar = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Uploaded image", upload_to='media', null=True)
```

Serialzier:

```
class AvatarStorageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
avatar = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)

class Meta:
    model = AvatarStorage

    fields = '__all__'
```

Views:

```
class UploadAvatar(APIView):
parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

def post(self, request, format=None):

    serializer = AvatarStorageSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

For posting, i am using Postman, over there settings: Body=>Form-Data and choosing a file from disk.

If it's important, this is API for mobile

Comment: I think Avatar field specification is not neccessary in AvatarStorageSerializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the code, I was missing required headers in Postman:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=upload.jpg;
```

Answer (score 2):

Update the setting files FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS to like this

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS=[
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
]
```

if you want to know more, [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers)

Comment: It doesn't help, also I need to use TemporaryFileUploadHandler instead of MemoryFileUploadHandler as my imgs around 5-10 mb, and MemoryFileUploadHandler was designed for max 2.5mb

Comment: I already implemented this thing, now i uploaded 8mb image. The image saved without any loss.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what is your problem